# PIL: fromarray gives a wrong object in P mode

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, python-imaging-library

I want to load an image in `P` mode, transform it into `np.array` and then transform it back, but I got a wrong Image object which is a gray image, not a color one

```
label = PIL.Image.open(dir).convert('P')
label = np.asarray(label)
img = PIL.Image.fromarray(label, mode='P')
img.save('test.png')
```

`dir` is the path of the original picture; `test.png` is a gray picture

Comment: I have modified the question and it is nearly the full code

Comment: Provide a sample image here.

Comment: Also, it's because you discard the palette. You have to open in 'P' mode, not convert to it.

Comment: What happens if you do `label.save('preconvert.png')` immediately after your first line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images in 'P' mode require a palette that associates each color index with an actual RGB color. Converting the image to an array loses the palette, you must restore it again.

```
label = PIL.Image.open(dir).convert('P')
p = label.getpalette()
label = np.asarray(label)
img = PIL.Image.fromarray(label, mode='P')
img.setpalette(p)
img.save('test.png')
```

Answer (score -1):

(I cannot comment, on the above post)
Small correction on the above code:
`img.putpalette(p)` (instead of `setpalette`)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34627377)